# JQuery targeting individual lists for Equalheights on a page with multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a page that will be ever growing with categories of similar lists and I need to set Equal Heights for a single given `<ul>` group.

My basic HTML is:

```
<div class="item-list row-1">
    <h2>Row 1</H2>
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-h-c-153-256-3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-153-113-5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-h-c-153-221-1.jpg"></li>    
</ul>

</div>

<div class="item-list row-2">
<h2>Row 2</H2>
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-95-2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-169-152-1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-169-96-3.jpg"></li>     
</ul>
</div>
```

... and then I use the JQuery Equalheights plugin as such:

```
$(".item-list ul li").siblings().equalHeights(50,400);​
```

... to set Equal Height on UL groups. The issue is that I cannot seem to specify Equal Heights for each unordered list on the page. I know I could do this theoretically by targeting row-1, row-2 and then the Equal Heights would be specific for the tallest element in each UL Group but that would get messy for JQuery as the groups of ULs grow.

So far I have tried using `.siblings()` to just try to target each indivdual UL group but I still see the same global height of the tallest element on the page set for every `ul > li` no matter where it is.

I have a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/nDLg5/39/

... and if you inspect the `<li>` tags, you can see they all have a height set to 260px but in reality Row 2 `<li>` tags should have a much smaller height set. I also played around with `.closest()` but had no luck there either. If you are not familar with EqualHeights, you can have a look [here at the docu.](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, to apply the `.equalHeights()` to the li's in each `<ul>` , do like this:

```
$(".item-list ul").each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').equalHeights(50,400);
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/nDLg5/21/embedded/result/) (I added lightblue background to better show the heights)

Comment: yes, perfect! Thanks. BTW, didn't know about JSfiddle "embedded", that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
$(".item-list").find('img').css({'height' : '100px'});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/WJ9jS/)

Or this?

```
$(".item-list").find('ul li *').css({'height' : '100px'});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/WJ9jS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:
var itemlists = document.getElementsByClassName('item-list');

this will return an array wich contains all of your elements with item-list class.

then you have to simply walk on this array.